Use residues to verify the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{1/2}}{(x+1)^2} dx$
I found this question on page $285$ of the book COMPLEX ANALYSIS FOR MATHEMATICS AND ENGINEERING by J, Mathews.
I tried to draw the contour and calculate the contour integral and each path integral,but I made a mistake somewhere, and I don't know where I went wrong.
Thank you for any help and orientation.


The work is a little hard to follow, but there's a branch point at the origin where the contour you drew crosses over. Choosing this contour in this link here with $\operatorname{arg}z \in [0,2\pi)$ should be a good start because the line segments above and below the positive real axis would help recover the original integral you want.

Please don't use images as they're unsearchable and many people can't access them at all. It's also extremely difficult to read what you're written.

You could change variables to $y=\sqrt x$, then the pole is at $y=i$

It' probably better to regularize by
$$\sqrt{x} = \sinh u,\quad dx = 2 \sinh u \ \cosh u \ du, \quad (1+x)=\cosh^2 u$$
and use the periodicity of the hyperbolic functions in imaginary direction
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{(1+x)^2} \ dx = 2\ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sinh ^2 y}{\cosh ^3 y} \ dx, $$
an even function with a pole at $y=\frac{i \pi}{2},$ evaluation along the boundary of an   infinite strip $0<\Im y<\pi$
